# Get two value inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a "real-time" checker which checks the input the user has given to check if it's already available on the database (e.g. username, phone number)

the input box:

```
<input type = "text" name = "user_username" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="chkstudidnumber(this.value)" autocomplete="off" required/><br/>
<div id = "msg"></div>
```

the javascript:

```
<script>
  function chkstudidnumber(val)
  {
      $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"check_username.php",
        data:'username='+val,
        success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
        }
      });
  }
</script>
```

and finally the php file:

```
<?php
include("dev_connection.php");

$g_username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
$stud_username = mysqli_escape_string($con,$g_username);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$stud_username' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
  echo "<div id = 'msg_error'>";
  echo "<img src = './img/img_error.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;vertical-align:middle;'> ";
  echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;that username is already registered<br/>";
  echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if you forgot your password, please contact us";
  echo "</div>";
} else {
  echo "<div id = 'msg'>";
  echo "<img src = './img/img_check2.png' style='height:10px;width:10px;'> ";
  echo "username available";
  echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Now, I want to do this on my firstname and lastname input box

```
<input type = "text" name = "user_firstname" placeholder="Firstname"autocomplete="off" required/>
<input type = "text" name = "user_lastname" placeholder="Lastname"autocomplete="off" required/>
```

How can I apply the same javascript (or create a new one) to combine the two inputs into something like `check_name.php?fname=samplename&lname=samplelastname`

Answer (score 1):

Change your function so that it can accept more then one params like:

```
function chkstudidnumber(val1, val2)
{
    $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"check_username.php",
        data: {
            'fname' : val1,
            'lname' : val2
        },
        success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `$('form').serialize()` in ajax `data` function to get all the form input's on php page so that you can have all input's like username, first name, last name and all.

**Try This:**

```
<script>
  function chkstudidnumber(val)
  {
      $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"check_username.php",
        data:$('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
        }
      });
  }
</script>
```

If you have multiple form on the page then you can also provide `class` or `id` to the form and use that with `serialize` function to post that form data only.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  function chkstudidnumber()
  {
   var firstName = $("input[name=user_firstname]").val();
   var lastName = $("input[name=user_lastname]").val();
          $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"check_username.php",
        data:'username='+firstName+'lastname='+lastName,
        success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
        }
      });
  }
</script>

<input type = "text" name = "user_firstname" placeholder="Firstname"autocomplete="off" required/>
<input type = "text" name = "user_lastname" placeholder="Lastname"autocomplete="off" required onkeyup="chkstudidnumber()" />
```

Comment: why is there a ` var a = $("input[name=user_lastname]").val();` ?

Comment: @Dranreb It was just misprint line. I have removed that line.

Comment: It works but has flaws. When I "get" the `fname` and `lname` in the php, it only reads the `fname` which is for example I wrote "firstname" in the firstname box and "lastname" in the lastname box, the output of `fname` is `firstnamelname=lastname` while the `lname` is not detected.